# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.orm.Database com.orm.SugarApp.getDatabase()' on a null object referenc

Tags: android

I am using Android Studio to develop my android application. In my application i need some db sqlite operations. I start using Sugar ORM. According to the latest version sugar 1.3.jar does not need any context initialization.

So that i start coding like this

```
Iterator<Order> orders = Order.findAll(Order.class);

<meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="dbname.db" />
    <meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="2" />
    <meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true" />
    <meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="value" />
```

in menifast file.

but i faced a problem is

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{package.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException:
>   Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.orm.Database
>   com.orm.SugarApp.getDatabase()' on a null object referenc

Do you think i need to do something else or missed something ??
Please help.

thanks

Answer (score 8):

Your AndroidManifest.xml file should look like:
And make sure you have **android:name="com.orm.SugarApp"** inside application tag.

```html
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon"
android:name="com.orm.SugarApp">
.
.
<meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="sugar_example.db" />
<meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="2" />
<meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true" />
<meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="com.example" />
.
.
</application>
```

More info: http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html

Comment: Do I can set other name for my app (I create class for caching data from database) and save efficiency Sugar-db?