# Sugar ORM can't save in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, sugarorm

I have a class which extends `SugarRecord`, here is it:

```
class Advertiser : SugarRecord<Advertiser> {
    var number: String? = null
    var name: String? = null

    constructor() {}

    constructor(number: String, name: String) {
        this.number = number
        this.name = name
    }
}
```

I have sugar metadata in manifest:

```
    <meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="sugar_example.db" />
    <meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="2" />
    <meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true" />
    <meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="com.example" />
```

I'm trying to create new instance of `Advertiser` and save it in `MainActivity.kt`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val advertiser = Advertiser("123123", "test advertiser")
        advertiser.save()





    }
}
```

but I'm getting exception, here is stack trace:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                            Process: ge.ketili.team.blocksms, PID: 22305
>                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{ge.ketili.team.blocksms/ge.ketili.team.blocksms.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'com.orm.Database com.orm.SugarApp.getDatabase()' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2706)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1514)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6205)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
>                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'com.orm.Database com.orm.SugarApp.getDatabase()' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                                at com.orm.SugarRecord.save(SugarRecord.java:45)
>                                                                                at ge.ketili.team.blocksms.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:15)
>                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6864)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)

Comment: Full stack trace?

Comment: just exact cause of exception

Comment: Is that your full stack trace from Logcat?

Comment: noo, it is just snippet of full stack trace

Comment: Post the full stack trace please

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Where are you doing this bit of code? You are taking into account the application lifecycle right?

        `val advertiser = Advertiser("123123", "test advertiser")
        advertiser.save()`

Comment: Also, possible duplicate:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30660601/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-com-orm-database-com-orm-sugarapp-getdatabase

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.orm.Database com.orm.SugarApp.getDatabase()' on a null object referenc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30660601/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-com-orm-database-com-orm-sugarapp-getdatabase)

Comment: I edited my question again, look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application should be `SugarApp` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<application android:name="com.orm.SugarApp"
...
</application>
```

Comment: Note you can also make your application class extend SugarApp if you don't want to give up your `name` attribute.